# Minimizing sum of absolute deviations

Tags: linear-programming, linear-regression

Suppose we want to find coefficients $b$ in $\underset{b}{\operatorname{argmin}} \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n | y_{i}-b_{1}x_{i}-b_{0}\mid$.

If we rewrite this problem in terms of linear programming, we can use two different ways:
1. $$min \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |z_{i}|$$
   subject to  $z_{i}>=y_{i}-b_{1}x_{i}-b_{0}$; $z_{i}>=-y_{i}+b_{1}x_{i}+b_{0}$
or another way:
.  $$min \displaystyle\sum\limits_{i=1}^n |z_{i}^{+}+z_{i}^{-}|$$ 
   subject to $z_{i}^{+}-z_{i}^{-}=y_{i}-b_{1}x_{i}-b_{0}$

My question is which way is "better" in terms of computational performance for a standard linear solver for large number of b coefficients and observations.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is also known as a median regression which is a special case of a quantile regression. “For large number of $b$ coefficients and observations” using a standard solver is not going to be efficient. There are freely available tools to perform a median regression –  e.g. R see http://hosho.ees.hokudai.ac.jp/~kubo/Rdoc/library/quantreg/html/rq.html The Barrodale and Roberts algorithm is a modified simplex method. If the problem is not too large, confidence intervals can be easily obtained.

Comment: The reason I've asked this question is that I want to use LAD LASSO regression $\min_{\beta} \left| \mathbb{y} - \mathbb{X} \boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1 + \lambda \left|\boldsymbol{\beta}\right|_1$ and be able to have constraints on coefficients. I've asked it here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76538/positively-constrained-parameters-in-lad-lasso/76542#76542